# Is this an inefficient approach? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm making a simple game/webapp where you press a button and it generates a random number. Basically, I want there to be a "team scores" and you each time you press the button your score is equal to the random value generated.

Scoreboard will look like this:

1. Bob - 500
2. Steve - 340
3. Joe - 260

I thought of doing it in a process like this:

1. Each time user presses button, do an ajax call to php script which will store score in mysql table
2. Also near the same time retrieve all values from that table and update the score menu

My question is, will this be inefficient if there are thousands of users using my app? The user in my app will be able to press the button very rapidly so I think SQL operations would be greatly delayed if there are a lot of users. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Yes, but only until the user presses the button again which should update the highscores. I'm worried about it because user can rapidly update his scores so not sure how well it would scale to many users. Maybe I shouldn't be using a database for this?

Comment: But why would a score be random and why would a user want to update his score five times in a row? I don't get it, but wouldn't it make more sense to let the user click random numbers, and explicitly confirm when he wants to persist data?

Comment: If you are only looking to do a scoreboard, you may want to either A) do a query to get the highest score for that user, and only store their new score if its higher than their highest OR B) store all scores in one table, and the highest score for each user in another table. Doing either A or B will cut down on the size of your tables that you have to parse through, as the game grows you could get a lot of rows.

Comment: Its the game mechanics. Goal is to generate the highest number and be on the top of your team's (five man team) scoreboard. I wanted it to be near realtime, where scores are pushed/retrieved from and to server for everyone once they press the generate button.

Comment: @john: the problem with that is that the highscore is not necessarily a HIGH score, but a score keeper. The catch about my game is that your number can also decrease when generated, which will make you go lower on the board. Each press will affect your score. I'm mainly worried about the latency when fetching and setting scores. I want everyone to see the same scores.

Comment: *You could simply update the score every 5 seconds or so if you want to reduce load ie (if score changed, and 5 seconds passed since last update => update)

Comment: Strange. Anyhow, the number of concurrent Ajax requests is browser dependent. you could wait for the Ajax call to return before allowing to send a new request.